# How to make a blur like in the photo using pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I cut out the bottom part of the photo and tried to sort through the pixels and do it using them, but it still didn’t work out for me, I tried using the blur that Pillow offers, but that’s not the same either, and I couldn’t find any other methods other than those which I used. In the photo there is a transition from one photo to another on the left side, I need to do something like that, previously this was done using photoshop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94eDW.png)

Comment: We need to see your images and your [mcve] in order to help you. Please click [edit] and add both. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
blur_width = image.width // blur_width_constant #blur_width_constant is  user defined
mask = Image.new('L', (image.width, image.height), 0)
mask_np = np.array(mask)
for i in range(blur_width):
    mask_np[:, i] = int(255 * (i / blur_width))  
mask = Image.fromarray(mask_np)

blurred_image = image.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(blur_radius))#blur_width is  user defined
final_image = Image.composite(blurred_image, image, mask)
```

This is the best I can provide with the limited context. Things to take care I have added a masking layer for blurring so you can blur out the area which you want by changing the mask.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFilter
img = Image.new('RGB', (300, 200), color = 'white')
d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
d.rectangle([50, 50, 150, 150], outline='black', fill='blue')
img.save('sample_image.jpg')

##################################Generated a image
image = Image.open('sample_image.jpg')
blur_width = image.width // 10  

mask = Image.new('L', (image.width, image.height), 0)
mask_np = np.array(mask)
for i in range(blur_width):
    mask_np[:, i] = int(255 * (i / blur_width))  
mask = Image.fromarray(mask_np)

blurred_image = image.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(25))  
final_image = Image.composite(blurred_image, image, mask)
final_image.show()
```

where I guess the **blur_radius** of gaussian blur is self explanatory. But coming to **blur_width_constant** it is how much are from right you wanted to be blurred. It is getting used for generation of mask but mask can be as per your design, but once the mask is generated then the same flow can be followed as per requirement.

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't really help. You have removed the `import` statements thereby making it unrunnable and you give no indication of what it does. Nor is there any indication of what `blur_width` is or should be, only a recursive initialisation in terms of itself?

Comment: Totally agreed with you. That is why upvote your query too. Now comin to the part that my function is not runnable let me make some changes so you can run it. Also blur width is nothing but how much of area from right you wanted to be blur if you see then you will find it is getting used in mask.

Comment: @MarkSetchell hope this answers your query from my end

Comment: Miles more useful. Thank you for taking the time to improve it.

Comment: Sure like I am used to providing only the corrected segment and done with it. ;)